# Power towers Power towers from x to n

Tags: numerics, evaluation

How can I make Mathematica calculate a power tower for a succession of numbers, but instead of writing them, Mathematica does the iterative calculation.

```
     cal= 99^2^3^-----1000
```

How to make mathematics write it and if you can calculate it?

I understand that there may be an overflow of memory upon actual calculation, it can also help me

Comment: There are two possible implementations on [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can define

```
pt[n_] := Power @@ Flatten[{99, Range[2, n]}]
```

But it won't get you very far

```
Table[pt[n], {n, 2, 4}]
(* {9801, 9227446944279201, Overflow[]} *)
```

As a check

```
{99^2, 99^(2^3), 99^(2^(3^4))}
(* {9801, 9227446944279201, Overflow[]} *)
```

Comment: thank , How can I see what mathematics writes (the same as what you put with check)

Comment: @zeros Do you just want the formatting?  Something like `99^## & @@ HoldForm /@ Range[2, 7]` ?

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard , thanks that is very good, the previous routine could be used, so that it shows them and calculates them simultaneously until the overflow occurs

Comment: You could also use `Nest[]`: `Nest[99^# &, 1, 3]`.